# FullCalendar.io has last day wider than any other days

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying around [fullCalendar.io](https://fullCalendar.io) for the first time, and one annoying issue is that I can't make the **last day in a Timeline view** to be the **same width** as every other day...

I understand the technical part as they say in the [`slotWidth`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotWidth) documentation, but it's still annoying ‍♂️

[image]

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

here's a simple [example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/balexandre/full/WNvVLjR) that has the exact issue... if you can't see it, just resize the window a bit

[Small video is also available](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbpa4ds3svsvqx9/question_61081406.mp4?dl=0) or just to see the exact issue with [smaller changes to the window](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xw3n43xycpmarw/question_61081406_2.mp4?dl=0)

---

Note: events will only load for April 2020 as they hard coded

Comment: I spent quite a while and I couldn't get the demo to reproduce what's in your screenshot. Can you give more specific instructions? P.S. we can't really fix internal bugs with fullCalendar here (which is likely to be what this is, unless you've screwed something up in the CSS, which I couldn't see any evidence of in your demo). We can help you with usage of fullCalendar. But if you've found a bug in the package itself, you'll need to [report it](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) to the maintainers of the project.

Comment: @ADyson here's a [simple screendump](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbpa4ds3svsvqx9/question_61081406.mp4?dl=0) as well a [even simpler one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xw3n43xycpmarw/question_61081406_2.mp4?dl=0) from my dropbox account

Comment: Ok I managed to reproduce it by gradually making the viewport smaller, as per the second video. But then I stopped and watched for a couple of seconds and the calendar then auto-corrected the size itself. It didn't always end up 100% perfect, but usually it was close enough that you'd barely notice.

Comment: I can confirm that depending on the viewport width, there is a slightly difference between the last <th> width and of the rest.

Comment: Well like I said it's probably due to a slight glitch in the internal calculations performed by fullCalendar. So if it's bothering you, you'd need to file a bug report. Not sure there's anything we can help you with here.